# Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Setup\Module\I18n\Locale' not found

Tags: magento2.3.5

I have just upgrade Magento version to 2.3.5 and when I am trying to login into admin I am getting error like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Setup\Module\I18n\Locale' not found in /cache/vendor/magento/module-release-notification/Model/ContentProvider/Http/HttpContentProvider.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /cache/vendor/magento/module-release-notification/Ui/DataProvider/Modifier/Notifications.php(202): Magento\ReleaseNotification\Model\ContentProvider\Http\HttpContentProvider->getContent('2.3.5', 'community', 'en_us') #1 /cache/vendor/magento/module-release-notification/Ui/DataProvider/Modifier/Notifications.php(106): Magento\ReleaseNotification\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Notifications->getNotificationContent() #2 /cache/vendor/magento/module-release-notification/Ui/DataProvider/NotificationDataProvider.php(104): Magento\ReleaseNotification\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Notifications->modifyMeta(Array) #3 /cache/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(318): Magento\ReleaseNotification\Ui\DataProvider\NotificationDataProvider->getMeta() #4 /cache/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(218) in /cache/vendor/magento/module-release-notification/Model/ContentProvider/Http/HttpContentProvider.php on line 60
```

Once I refresh the page it has gone and all working fine. just get error while login first time.
Any idea about Error? any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command and check:

bin/magento indexer:reindex

It may help you to resolve issue.

Comment: applied but not working...